# How to get one attribute from list of custom objects

Tags: java, guava, jxpath

Java - JxPath - Spring

I have `List<MyClass> myClassList` filled with `MyClass` objects. I am trying to find a cleanest and fastest way to get `Set<String> a` property out of `myClassList`.

```
class MyClass{

  private String a;
  private String b;


  // setters getters

}
```

I am using jxpath for searching but I am not sure it can also do what I mentioned above.

```
JXPathContext ctx = JXPathContext.newContext(myClassList);
Iterate<String> aProps = ctx.iterate("? what to write");
```

Can you help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

instead of Jxpath there is way doing it in Guava library.

here is the implementation

```
    public static final Function<Obj, String> FOO = new Function<Obj, String>() {
            public String apply(Obj input) {
                return input.foo;
            }
        };

List<String> fooList = Lists.transoform(targetList, Object.FOO)
or 
List<String> fooList = Collections2.transoform(targetList, Object.FOO)
```